# How to convert QueryThreadCycleTime() to seconds?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

The Windows function [`QueryThreadCycleTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/realtimeapiset/nf-realtimeapiset-querythreadcycletime) gives the number of "CPU clock cycles" used by a given thread. The Windows manual boldly states

> Do not attempt to convert the CPU clock cycles returned by QueryThreadCycleTime to elapsed time.

I would like to do exactly this, for most Intel and AMD x86_64 CPUs.
It doesn't need to be very accurate, because you can't expect perfection from cycle counters like [RDTSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) anyway.
I just need some kludgey way to get the time factor `seconds / QueryThreadCycleTime` for the CPUs.

First, I imagine that `QueryThreadCycleTime` uses RDTSC internally.
I imagine that on some CPUs, constant rate TSC is used, so changing the actual clock rate (e.g. with variable-frequency CPU power management) doesn't affect the `time/TSC` factor.
On other CPUs, that rate might change, so I'd have to query this factor periodically.

#### Why do I need this?

Before anyone cites the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), I should note that I'm not really interested in alternative solutions.
This is because I have two hard requirements for profiling that no other method meets.

- It should only measure thread time, so `sleep(1)` should *not* return 1 second, but a busy loop lasting 1 second *should*. In other words, the profiler should not say that a task ran for 10ms when its thread was only active for 1ms. This is the reason I cannot use [`QueryPerformanceCounter()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/profileapi/nf-profileapi-queryperformancecounter).
- It needs a precision better than 1/64 seconds, which is the precision given by [`GetThreadTimes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getthreadtimes). The tasks I'm profiling might run for only a few microseconds.

#### Minimal reproducable example

As requested by @Ted Lyngmo, the goal is implement `computeFactor()`.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

double computeFactor();

int main() {
    uint64_t start, end;
    QueryThreadCycleTime(GetCurrentThread(), &start);
    // insert task here, such as an actual workload or sleep(1)
    QueryThreadCycleTime(GetCurrentThread(), &end);
    printf("%lf\n", (end - start) * computeFactor());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "_'m not really interested in alternative solutions_" to what solution? What is your current, non-working, solution (in code)?

Comment: I don't think it's relevant to the question, but https://github.com/VCVRack/Rack/blob/v1/src/system.cpp#L190-L194 is the current measurement method, and https://github.com/VCVRack/Rack/blob/v1/src/engine/Engine.cpp#L258-L274 is how the timing is used. The end-user result is https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/199190471258537985/614624162207760394/2019-08-23-205653_670x619_scrot.png

Comment: The reason why I asked for your current, non-working, solution was to make you publish it to trigger people to give an answer. I personally think it's relevant and won't try to answer without it.

Comment: Fair enough. You can try the result in production with the Windows build of VCV Rack 1.1.4 (https://vcvrack.com/Rack.html) and by enabling "Engine > CPU meter".

Comment: Can you convert that into a [mcve]?

Comment: Added minimal example.

Comment: Great (although I don't think my request for more info is relevant for people trying to help).  The answer to the question is: You *can't*. It's described in the documentation why that won't work. "_This function uses timer services provided by the CPU, which can vary in implementation. For example, some CPUs will vary the frequency of the timer when changing the frequency at which the CPU runs and others will leave it at a fixed rate._" - My computer ramps up from x to x*2 cycles/s and back again in ~no-time. Converting that to elapsed time is something a hardware profiler may do.

Comment: When an API is documented as not being suitable for a specific purpose, and the publisher of that API is extremely knowledgeable about the subject (MS isn't joeblow@mymomsbasement.com), you should accept that as being accurate information. Having the expectation that they know less than you do and you can make it work anyway is somewhat unreasonable, and expecting us to do that work for you is even more unreasonable. What you're asking isn't going to work, and instead of wasting your time trying to do it anyway you should reverse your position on seeking alternative solutions.

Comment: Also, as a side note: Most people who ask questions that say *Here's what I want to do, It's absolutely the wrong way to do this, and everything I've read on the subject says it won't work, but I insist on doing it this way anyway, and my mind is made up so don't bother telling me about any other way to do what I want to do* end up sorely disappointed. Having a closed mind about more appropriate solutions is almost certainly not going to work out well.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Okay, thanks. Many other answerers seem to avoid answering "it's impossible" despite it being the correct answer in many cases. However, I don't think it is in this case. Given some processor model with some power setting, the limit `time / QueryThreadCycleTime` as time -> infinity is well-defined and therefore exists. I address your quote about constant vs. variable TSC on models of CPUs in the original post's third paragraph. It's probably true that there's no easy answer, and that the answer is probably too difficult for non-contract work, but I don't think it's impossible.

Comment: @KenWhite I disagree that this documentation is correct in 100% of cases. There always exists a corner case where a blanket statement (like "do not attempt to do this") does not apply. This is such a case. My goal is to solve the problem in any way possible, not solve it in "my way". There is no arrogance in this matter. What I'm asking you is assume for the moment that my research is not flawed, and to consider my question as an "isolated question", completely academically and separate from application.

Comment: Got it. *While the manufacturers of screwdrivers all say that their products are only to be used for screws, I insist on doing everything with a screwdriver. My goal is to build my entire house using a screwdriver, despite the fact that it is impossible to correctly install plumbing, insulation, and framing using that tool. I found one person that was able to drive a nail with a screwdriver, so please respect my research efforts. That person knows more than the engineers that designed screwdrivers.* You win. Good luck.

Comment: @KenWhite I don't see what your comments offer to this discussion or why you chose to join this thread. On the other hand, TedLyngmo's answer has given inspiration for a clever solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Do not attempt to convert the CPU clock cycles returned by QueryThreadCycleTime to elapsed time.**

> **I would like to do exactly this.**

Your wish is obviously **Denied**!

A workaround, that will do something close to what you want, could be to create one thread with a `steady_clock` that samples `QueryThreadCycleTime` and/or `GetThreadTimes` at some specified frequency. Here's an example of how it could be done with a sampling thread taking a sample of both once every second.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;

struct FTs_t {
    FILETIME CreationTime, ExitTime, KernelTime, UserTime;
    ULONG64 CycleTime;
};

using Sample = std::vector<FTs_t>;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const FILETIME& ft) {
    std::uint64_t bft = (std::uint64_t(ft.dwHighDateTime) << 16) + ft.dwLowDateTime;
    return os << bft;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Sample& smp) {
    size_t tno = 0;
    for (const auto& fts : smp) {
        os << " tno:" << std::setw(3) << tno << std::setw(10) << fts.KernelTime
           << std::setw(10) << fts.UserTime << std::setw(16) << fts.CycleTime << "\n";
        ++tno;
    }
    return os;
}

// the sampling thread
void ft_sampler(std::atomic<bool>& quit, std::vector<std::thread>& threads, std::vector<Sample>& samples) {
    auto tp = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); // for steady sampling

    FTs_t fts;
    while (quit == false) {
        Sample s;
        s.reserve(threads.size());
        for (auto& th : threads) {
            if (QueryThreadCycleTime(th.native_handle(), &fts.CycleTime) &&
                GetThreadTimes(th.native_handle(), &fts.CreationTime,
                               &fts.ExitTime, &fts.KernelTime, &fts.UserTime)) {
                s.push_back(fts);
            }
        }
        samples.emplace_back(std::move(s));

        tp += 1s; // add a second since we last sampled and sleep until that time_point
        std::this_thread::sleep_until(tp);
    }
}

// a worker thread
void worker(std::atomic <bool>& quit, size_t payload) {
    volatile std::uintmax_t x = 0;
    while (quit == false) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < payload; ++i) ++x;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1us);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::atomic<bool> quit_sampling = false, quit_working = false;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    std::vector<Sample> samples;
    size_t max_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency() > 1 ? std::thread::hardware_concurrency() - 1 : 1;

    // start some worker threads
    for (size_t tno = 0; tno < max_threads; ++tno) {
        threads.emplace_back(std::thread(&worker, std::ref(quit_working), (tno + 100) * 100000));
    }

    // start the sampling thread
    auto smplr = std::thread(&ft_sampler, std::ref(quit_sampling), std::ref(threads), std::ref(samples));

    // let the threads work for some time
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(10s);

    quit_sampling = true;
    smplr.join();

    quit_working = true;
    for (auto& th : threads) th.join();

    std::cout << "Took " << samples.size() << " samples\n";

    size_t s = 0;
    for (const auto& smp : samples) {
        std::cout << "Sample " << s << ":\n" << smp << "\n";
        ++s;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is likely what I will be doing. In other words, compute an approximation to the limit `steady_clock / QueryThreadCycleTime()` as time -> infinity. What I can't figure out is how to guarantee that the thread computing this approximation doesn't get context-switched by the OS, thus messing up the `steady_clock` measurement. I could compute it several times and take the minimum.

Comment: If you want guarantees, you need a real-time OS. What you as an observer can do (without an RTOS) is to use `steady_clock` to compensate. That part won't be too bad.

Comment: Hmm, now that I think about it, I can use Windows' `GetThreadTimes()` to make this measurement. It runs in the same "time reference frame" as `QueryThreadCycleTime()`, unlike `steady_clock`, so the ratio between the former two measurements is the factor that I'm after! I can launch a thread that busy-waits for about 1 second and measure both `GetThreadTimes()` and `QueryThreadCycleTime()`, divide them, and that's the factor!

Comment: That sounds like a much better option, but I suggest a `steady_clock` or `high_resolution_clock` and `std::this_thread::sleep_until(<time_point>)` for doing  the actual sampling.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work, since both `GetThreadTimes()` and `QueryThreadCycleTime()` would both return ~0 if a thread simply yields as its "workload". The point of those functions is to *not* count when a thread is inactive.

Comment: @Vortico I added an example that I hope explains what I was thinking better than I put it in words.